# Distribution Algorithm

Tags: c#, algorithm, list, grouping, knapsack-problem

I have a list of class Item:

```
public class Item
{
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public string Name { get; set; }
   public int ItemSize { get; set; }
   public int? ContainerId { get; set; }
}
```

and also a class Container

```
public class Container
{
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public int ContainerSize { get; set; }
}
```

A container have a Max Value for the property Size.
I need to assign each object of List to a container, taking care about these rules:

1. Object of List Item which share the same name MUST be placed on the same Container. Of course it is impossible to have a number of Item with the same Name with TotalSize > Max Container Size.
2. I have to create the less possibile number of Containers

Any advice is greatly appreciated.

Comment: So if you have more items with the same name than the maximal container size, then you should put the overflown items into a new container or just don't care about the overflow ?

Comment: you tagged it right: use a knapsack algorithm

Comment: @AttilaBujáki I can't have the "overflow". The input Data will prevent it.

Comment: Least possible number of containers? Easy - create one container that has a container size of `MyListItemList.Count` and put everything in it. Both your conditions are then satisfied. I'm guessing though this isn't the complete problem and that actually you are given a set of containers with a fixed size to begin with ...

Comment: @Mashton A container have a Max Value for ContainerSize Property

Comment: I recommend you to read the book "Introduction to Algorithms", 3rd edition of Thomas H. Corner & Others, page 465. It addresses you problem in depth, is better to understand and solve, than having someone doing it for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Split the items by Container ID and use a knapsack algorithm to solve the separate problem instances.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem

Comment: I have no container at start. The goal is to create them. Maybe I have misunderstood the answer ?

Comment: Then for each ID that occurs, create a container.